why can i do early return when its not allowed in react?
import React,{useState} from 'react';

function Car() {
  const [st, setSt] = useState(0);
  return <h2>a Car!</h2>;
}

export function App(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 
  if(count===3) return ;
  let b=<Car/>
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Car/>    
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

when rendering app usestate at top level run fine. But when count reaches 3 when we press the button 3 times, it does early return rendering nothing. But there are hooks in car component that didnt run.So for hooks doesnt that count as early return that it did not render the hooks part in car.so all of the hooks didn't run.Can you explain?

Return ´null´ instead

@devpolo it doesnt make a difference

It's unclear what you are specifically asking for help with here. Please [edit] to clarify the question and/or what any specific issue or problem is you need help with.

When you write JSX like <Car/> or
return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Car/>    
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );

... you are not calling the Car function or executing any of the hooks it contains. <Car /> is roughly the same as calling createElement(Car, null), and all that that does is produce a small object looking roughly like this:
{
  type: Car,
  props: null,
  ref: null
}

With more complicated JSX you make a larger object, but you're again not calling the Car function or any hooks.
Once you've built up as large of an object as you like, you return it and thus you tell react "here are the things i would like to render to the page". If you've returned anything, react will recusively step through the child components and now it will end up calling Car and its hooks. But this happens after the return, and so react knows that you've ended one component and are starting another.
The rules of hooks don't say that you can't change how many components you're returning. You can return a <Car/> on one render, and then skip it on the next one. All that matters is that during the course of App executing, you must call the same hooks in the same order.

at first it calls hooks of car component. but when we increase count to 3 it does return and in that case hooks of car component will not be called as it is not reaching that statement. will that not counted as early return in hooks?

at first it calls hooks of car component What line of code calls hooks of car component? There's a line of code in react's codebase that does that, but none of the code you showed calls Car.

when b is assigned .when car component is rendered it must have called hooks of car component also

when b is assigned <Car/> All that line does does is create an object looking like { type: Car, props: null, ref: null } and assign it to b. Car is not called. when car component is rendered  Yes, but that's in the future, and react is the one that will render it. React knows when it starts rendering a component and starts the hook count over.

This code does not violate the rule about not having an early return before a hook, since the hook is in a separate component. The rule is just that you cannot have any hook calls that run conditionally within a component. Any conditions within the parent component, however, do not matter.
So if you formed your component like this:
function App {
  const {state1, setState1} = useState(false);
  if (state1 === true) return null;
  const {state2, setState2} = useState(0);

  return <div></div>;
}

Then you would be violating hook rules. But if state2 was inside a second, conditionally rendered child component, as it is in your code above, the hook rules would not be being violated.

can you tell me why usestate inside car component in return statement doesnt run when count=3 isnt case of early return?

It's a bit hard to understand what you are asking.  "when count=3 isnt case of early return" is hard to parse as written. do you mean that when count !== 3, the Car component's state hook is not being called?

when we first rendered usestate inside car component is called.But when we increase count to 3 it will  return rendering nothing.At this state usestate of count is not being called.Isnt it a case of early return?

still very hard to understand your question (perhaps there is a language barrier) but if I understand you correctly...when count reaches 3, useState of count is still being called, since it is at the top of the App component, and runs before you early return. the state within Car is wiped clean because you unmount the Car component when you stop rendering it. does this answer your question?

sorry i meant usestate of car is not being called when count reaches 3.all hhhoks should be executed in react and early return is not allowed. doesnt this violate that?

@Ujjawal no, since these are two separate components. as long as the hook is at the top of the component it is used within, before any early returns within that same component, you are fine.

@Ujjawal I have edited my answer to better address what I now believe your question to be.
